# Using sinon to spy/stub document.submit()

Tags: javascript, sinon, qunit

I have the following function called on Init() of SubmitCodePage:

```
 TrySubmit: function () {
            var $submitButton = $("#submitButton");

            if (!$submitButton.is(':disabled')) {
                $submitButton.submit();
            }
        }
```

I am trying to check that if the submit button is disabled, submit is not attempted. Here is my attempt at a QUnit test:

```
QUnit.test("TrySubmit - Submit button is disabled - submit not called", function (assert) {
    var $fixture = $("#qunit-fixture");

    // injects a disabled submit button: 
    $fixture.append(HTMLInjectorSubmitForm());

    submitMock = sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById').withArgs('submitButton').returns('submit');

    assert.ok(submitMock.notCalled, "Submit not called when button is disabled");
});
```

The test just runs and times out - I don't know how to check that the 'submit' is actually called?

Comment: What's `HTMLInjectorSubmitForm`? If it's not related, please remove it.

Comment: @slideshowp2 it injects the element I need for the test:
          `"<input id='submitButton' type='submit' class='disabled' disabled='disabled'>";`

Comment: Well, you're mocking out `getElementById`... but I'm not sure why, it is not used in your `TrySubmit` function (I'm not sure that `$('#foo')` uses it, jQuery could be using `document.querySelector()` instead). Also, where are you actually calling your `TrySubmit` function in your test? If you don't call that outer function, then the test would never get to the point of calling submit on your button.